# How to handle if we are getting 3 elements from a locating elements and i need to click 2nd one in cypress

Tags: cypress

How to handle if we are getting 3 elements from a locating elements and i need to click 2nd one in cypress
coz by using First() and Last() methods we can interact with last and first but for middle elements how we can do that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jlYl.png)

Answer (score 0):

[eq() does that](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax). You have to specify eq(1), because indexing starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cy.get('element').eq().click() as mentioned [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax)